# Insert into linked list fails in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to insert a new element to the tail of a user-created linked list.  Solution 1 fails but Solution 2 works and I am not able to figure out why:

```
  class Node {
     int data;
     Node next;
  }
```

Solution 1:

```
Node Insert(Node head,int data) {
        if(head == null) {
            head = new Node();
            head.data = data;
            head.next = null;
        } else {
            Node elem = head;
            while(elem != null) {
                elem = elem.next;
            }
            elem = new Node();
            elem.data = data;
            elem.next = null;
        }
        return head;
    }
```

Solution 2:

```
Node Insert(Node head,int data) {
        if(head == null) {
            head = new Node();
            head.data = data;
            head.next = null;
        } else {
            Node elem = head;
            while(elem.next != null) {
                elem = elem.next;
            }
            elem.next = new Node();
            elem = elem.next;
            elem.data = data;
            elem.next = null;
        }
            return head;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by fail? Are you getting an exception at runtime? You need to give much more detail as to what the problem is and how you've tried to solve it.

Comment: In solution 1, what is the purpose of the `while` loop, when you just discard the value of `elem` in the very next statement? *Hint: The answer to that question is the answer to your question.*

Comment: *BTW:* `head.next = null;` and `elem.next = null;` are redundant. `next` is already null on a new `Node`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In solution 1, you are navigating the list until you hit a null, and then you create a new `Node` that is not referenced by anything in the list:

```
Node elem = head;
while(elem != null) {
    elem = elem.next;
}
elem = new Node();
```

This final assignment doesn't change any of the elements in the list. Therefore your new `Node` does not join the list.

In solution 2, when you get to the last existing `Node` (that has a null as its `next` reference), you add the new `Node` as its `next` reference:

```
Node elem = head;
while(elem.next != null) {
    elem = elem.next;
}
elem.next = new Node(); /* This adds the node after the last node */
```

This works because your new `Node` is referenced by an existing element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

When the while loop ends, you end up in the last element of the linked list. The first solution is just overwriting that last element, instead you need to go to the next elem (elem.next) then add the data, which you are doing in the second solution

Comment: Solution 1 is not overriding anything. At the end of the loop, `elem` is null and a new `Node` is then created, but not hooked up to anything.

Comment: edit : I get your point now, but at the end of the loop he's at the last element which isn't null, but instead of jumping to the next node and calling new Node he's calling it on the last element

Comment: Yes the loop *clearly* says `while(elem != null)`, which means the loop will *only* end when `elem` **is** null. Ergo, `elem` is null when the loop ends.

Comment: Yes i misunderstood the loop, my bad

Answer (score -1):

It seems that in your first solution you find the last element in the list by iterating through it. While the last element is in variable "elem" you create a new element assigned to the same "elem" variable which causes you to lose the last element.

Comment: Solution 1 is not finding the last element. It is iterating right past the last element to a `null` value.